# How do I copy some text from within conkeror into my clipboard?

Tags: browser, conkeror

conkeror i'v started using it and its great! i cant find however how do i copy some text from within the browser into my clipboard?

Comment: Are you trying to do this programmatically? Or are you just trying to do the equivalent of Ctrl+C?

Comment: Why is this question tagged emacs ?

Comment: Hi
as conkeror has like emacs bindings i thought to tag it also to there... wasn't that right?
i'm interested in keyboard only selecting part of the browser text on screen and then doing the equivalent of CTRL-C...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In conkeror, the keyboard only method is first to i-Search for the
text you want to copy. Once you see the light grey highlight over the
first part of what you'd like to select, press Return. You may then use
the following keybindings to select text:

C-B -- one char back
C-F -- one char forward
M-B -- one word back
M-F -- one word forward

C-P -- back one line
C-N -- forward one line
S-down -- forward one line

Notice that those are shifted characters, so it's really C-S-b etc.

Use M-w to copy the text to the clipboard. Use C-h b to see the full
list of bindings. Try searching for "Extend selection."

The key is to highlight the first component of your desired
selection using i-Search.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the shortcut `* * T c` to copy full text from a DOM node. You must insert 4 characters: `*` then another `*` then `S-t` then `c`.

Answer (score 1):

Try ctrl-shift-c instead of ctr-c. The same change applies to pasting and cutting.

Comment: but i want to use keyboard only - not mouse how do i tell it where to start copying text and where to end?